# How do I send an email to all users that has flagged a node using rules?

Tags: rules, flags

I need to send an email when there is a new comment on a node to all users that have flagged that node? How do I do this?

The flag is called "Follow" and the content type is "Blog"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The exported code assumes use of Flag module to have a flag type as "follow" attached to Blog content type.

**As a summary:**

- set rule event as "After saving a new comment of type Blog comment".
- leave condition as none.
- set actions as

  - step 1: get all users
    who have flagged "Fetch users who have flagged a Node".
  - step2: loop
    through the list.

    - step2.1: send email

Here is the export for my Rule configured as per your requirement.

```
{ "rules_email_on_blog_comment" : {
    "LABEL" : "Email On Blog Comment",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "TAGS" : [ "blog", "email" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "flag", "rules", "comment" ],
    "ON" : { "comment_insert--comment_node_blog" : { "bundle" : "comment_node_blog" } },
    "DO" : [
      { "flag_fetch_users_node" : {
          "USING" : { "flag" : "follow", "node" : [ "comment:node" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "users" : { "users" : "Users who flagged" } }
        }
      },
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "users" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "mail" : {
                "to" : "[list-item:mail]",
                "subject" : "New Comment",
                "message" : "There is a new comment on the flagged blog post",
                "from" : "[site:mail]",
                "language" : [ "" ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What do I use in the "to" field for the email?

Comment: [list-item:mail] but you should be looping through all the fetched results before,you can try importing this rule so to get maximum out of it

Comment: I just need to take this one step further now. Any thought on how to check to ensure the users has the role of "member" before sending the email? Users can flag the content when they are members, but once they cease to be a member, I need to ensure they stop receiving that email. The user account remains but they just don't have the role anymore.

Comment: This settings seems like for Drupal 7. Any suggestions for 8? I cannot setup it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop to get all the users who have flagged, and you can add an action to send mail to all those users under that loop.